# Fonts loaded by useFonts but useCallback unable to detect and hide splashscreen

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am facing this issue that I have faced when trying to load custom fonts to react-native using expo workflow. This time the fonts have been loaded but the splashscreen is not hiding. I don't know much about how useCallback works but my assumption is its similar to useEffect only it used to listen to a variable state and run functions. I have followed the documentation on useFonts and still. Some forums says it would work on emulators but sometimes hang on real devices. Please take a look at my code and help me.

```
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import * as Splashscreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { Onboarding } from "./screens";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

Splashscreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
    fo_regular: require("./assets/fonts/regular.otf"),
    fo_bold: require("./assets/fonts/bold.otf"),
    fo_medium: require("./assets/fonts/medium.otf"),
    fo_light: require("./assets/fonts/light.otf"),
    fo_xtrabold: require("./assets/fonts/xtrabold.otf"),
  });
  console.log(fontsLoaded);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded || fontError) await Splashscreen.hideAsync();
  }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);

  if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError)
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="black" animating={fontsLoaded} />
    );

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Onboard"
          component={Onboarding}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

So there is a console log of fontsLoaded, that is how I know the fonts are loaded but the useCallback is not handling it.

Comment: Does this solve your issue?
[How to load custom fonts with the useFonts hook in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `useCallback` you want a `useEffect`

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (fontsLoaded || fontError) Splashscreen.hideAsync();
  }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);
```

[`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) is for undertaking an action when the values in the dependency array changes (in your case when either `fontsLoaded` or `fontError` have changed)

[`useCallback`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) is for memoizing a function

Comment: Well noted.. In the useFonts documentation you see they used useCallback and I assume is to memoize. Can I still use useEffect to call the useCallback once the component is loaded

Comment: The code inside the `useEffect` will be called (as a function) when the component is loaded when either `fontsLoaded` or `fontError` changes. You can memoize it as `useCallback`, but then you would have to call that function its own `useEffect` (which would run when the function changes, which might defeat the purpose of having saved it as a `useCallback`)